# Blockchain concepts - sending transactions

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have couple of questions regarding ethereum blockchain, hope someone can enlighten

1. If a user sends 2 transactions from his wallet with exact gas value, which one gets picked up by the miner first? The tx can be a simple tx like sending ether to another address. Is there a rule which states which tx will be picked up first?
2. Lets say - user A has 10 ether in his wallet. user sends 2 txs, 5 ether to Bob & 10 ether to Alice. How does the blockchain verifies both the txs? Does the blockchain verifies both the txs initially? If so, what happens during the time of actually ether sending. How does one of the tx is rejected?

any inputs will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming or any of the topics listed in this site's [help].

Answer (score 1):

> *with exact gas value, which one gets picked up by the miner first?*

It depends on the miner. But usually they order transactions from the same sender by their nonce - lowest to highest. ([source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-is-the-default-ordering-of-transactions-during-mining))

> *user A has 10 ether in his wallet. user sends 2 txs, 5 ether to Bob & 10 ether to Alice*

The first transaction (usually with the lower nonce, see above) succeeds. And the other fails because there's not enough ETH at the moment on the sender account. They are executed on the miner's EVM during the process of mining the block - that's where the status (success / fail) is generated.

If the example accounted for transaction fees, the 10 ETH transfer might always fail. Assumig the sender has exactly 10 ETH, they wouldn't be able to send "10 ETH + gas fees".